# SQL delete last space (if exist) in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have a database with a customer table. In this table there is, among other things, a column with email addresses (and other data). I searched for incorrectly entered email addresses, the application does not validate the entered data.

```
SELECT KnA_GIDNumer,KnA_EMail
FROM CDN.KntAdresy ka  
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ',KnA_EMail) > 0;
```

Output:

```
46  address1@gmail.com  
86  address2@example.pl 
139 address3@example.fm
```

How I can remove last space from email address?

Comment: Please read and follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [RTRIM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to remove the last spaces only, then use:

```
UPDATE CDN.KntAdresy
SET KnA_EMail = RTRIM(KnA_EMail);
```

And if you want to remove the spaces from both sides, then:

```
UPDATE CDN.KntAdresy
SET KnA_EMail = TRIM(KnA_EMail);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using this:

```
update CDN.KntAdresy
set KnA_EMail = REPLACE(KnA_EMail, ' ', '')
where CHARINDEX(' ',KnA_EMail) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE CDN.KntAdresy SET KnA_EMail = TRIM(KnA_EMail)
```

This will remove spaces in front and from the back of the field.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
update CDN.KntAdresy
set KnA_EMail = TRIM(KnA_EMail)
```

work fine, thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).